# How to retrieve text content of a node with getElementsByTagName in javascript?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to retrieve text content of a tag. I wrote this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var bono=document.getElementsByTagName("HYPHENATION");
alert(bono[0].data);
</script>
<HYPHENATION>mani</HYPHENATION>
</body>
</html>
```

but it gives me an error:

```
'bono.0.data' is null or not an object
```

what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/*
    Old

            $(document).ready(function(){
            var abc = document.getElementsByTagName("HYPHENATION")[0];
            document.write(abc.innerHTML)
        })
    */
```

try this

--html

```
<HYPHENATION>mani</HYPHENATION>
<HYPHENATION>mani1</HYPHENATION>
```

---javascript

```
 function setvalue()
    {
        var abc = document.getElementsByTagName("HYPHENATION")[1];
        var sethere = abc.innerHTML;
        document.write(abc.innerHTML)
        alert(sethere);
    }

setvalue()
```

Comment: you can use this in javascript function just remove document.ready part

Comment: It doesn't work @Ronjon.I want retrieve 'mani' string and save it in a variable.

Comment: thank you. in http://jsfiddle.net/ it works. bun when I save it in a HTML file and run it with firefox it doesn't works.

Comment: may be the javascript function load before finish the window load, 
try:
window.onload = function_name();